# Automatically checking / unchecking parent inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

I'm trying to automatically check parent items in an input list, but also uncheck children if the parent is unchecked.

The great thing is I found some code that replicates the desired functionality perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/3y3Pb/14/

EDIT: To clarify - the functionality required is this: Check mark a child input & all of the parent items get checked. Uncheck a Parent - all child inputs get unchecked. See the above example.

However, this doesn't seem to be working with my particular code (it's output from a WordPress plugin - Advanced Custom Fields) so I don't want to modify it).

I've narrowed it down to what I BELIEVE is the problem. ACF wraps each input with a `<label></label>`. I don't know why, but this breaks the functionality:

http://jsfiddle.net/3y3Pb/223/

When I remove the `<label></label>` it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/3y3Pb/225/

Changing the markup isn't really an option here, I would REALLY appreciate it if someone could assist me in making this work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the label - here is the solution:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
// if is checked
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).parents('li').children('label').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
} else {
    // uncheck all children
    $(this).closest('li').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This should work, its simple and only uses divs and a few lines of jquery:

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    var kids = $(this).next().next();
    if (kids.is('div') && !$(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        kids.children().each(function(){$(this).prop('checked',false)});
    }
    var thisChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    var master = $(this).parent().prevAll('[type="checkbox"]:first');
    master.prop('checked', thisChecked ? true : master.prop('checked'));
});
```

```css
div {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
div div {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />Master Check
<br />
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />Slave Check 1
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" />Slave Check 2
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" />Slave Check 3
    <br />
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />Slave 2 Check 1
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Slave 2 Check 2
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" />Slave 2 Check 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the javascript code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    // if is checked
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).parents('ul').children('li').children('label').find('input').prop('checked', true);

    } else {
      // uncheck all children
      $(this).closest('li').find('input').prop('checked', false);

    }

  });
});
```

`Children` travels a single level down the DOM tree, whereas `find` goes for multiple levels down looking into descendants.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - but that doesn't work. what needs to happen is this: Check mark a child, all parent items get checkmarked - uncheck a parent, all child elements get unchecked.

Comment: I misunderstood it then. So when a parent is unchecked, all child elements including the grandchildren will also be unchecked?

Comment: Hi Sajid, I appreciate the response - but i've solved it now! It was just the label...